# Tomcat clustering using UDP for replication

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'm approaching a migration of my clustering configuration in Tomcat. From the site documentation I can read that the communication module (Apache Tribe) can use both TCP and UDP for session replication but I couldn't find a parameter which can be used to switch from TCP (default I suppose) and UDP. 
Any help ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP is used (by default) for group membership and can be swithed off to TCP for example if you are running in a cloud environment where UDP is not suitable. For session replication, on the other hand TCP is used ("org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter"). 
Reference: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html and, if you are about [Tomcat migration](http://www.itbuzzpress.com/ebooks/from-tomcat-to-wildfly.html):